# How can we implement custom find methods in CrudRepository to get only specific columns from a database?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have to execute a SQL query in my repository:

```
public interface UserRequestResponseRepository extends JpaRepository<UserRequestResponse, Integer> {
    //public static final String FIND_QUERY = "select user.u_httpstatus ,user.u_queryparam from UserRequestResponse user";
    public static final String FIND_QUERY = 
            "select new com.abc.datacollection.entity.UserRequestResponse(user.u_httpstatus ,user.u_queryparam) from UserRequestResponse user";
    @Query(value = FIND_QUERY)
    public List<UserProjection> getAllRequestResponseRecords();
}
```

where UserProjection is a projection that I defined:

```
public interface UserProjection {
    String getU_httpstatus();
    String getU_queryparam();
}
```

The class userRequestResponse has more fields than u_httpstatus and u_queryparam, but I want only these 2 fields in my response.

```
public @ResponseBody List<UserRequestResponse> getAllRequestResponseRecords() {
    return userRequestResponseRepository.findAll() ;
}
```

how do I modify the above code (findAll()) to get results from my custom query and not the results from the default CrudRepository findAll()  (which returns all the fields).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you don't need to add a `@Query` to make projections work. Just having the `UserProjection` as the return type of the method in repository should be enough. More about this [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections)

Secondly, you can just have the following method in your repository as a projection-based findAll method;

```
public List<UserProjection> findAllProjectedBy();
```

Comment: Hey, I wanted to use query to do more complex SQL operations like counting based on groups, etc. How do I change the projection in that case? Or, any other method?

Comment: @ABHINAVSOOD I don't understand, in question you are saying, how do I get `UserProjection` response from `findAll` right? I answered that. For extra question please ask another one.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. Can you follow this link, I've posted my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215972/custom-sql-queries-in-crudrepository